# Is what happened to Ati ever expanded on?

Tags: sekien-no-inganock

During Sekien no Inganock -What a Beautiful People-, Ati is transformed and forced to attack Gii by Lemure Lemure, the only way to save her afterward was for Gii to erase all of Ati's memories effectively reverting her, and her mutations, to a Pre  state.

In the Web Novels which continue on from the end of the game, Ati encounters Prorishin in his reborn form and Kia appears, when Kia touched Ati Ati can see her Mutations which she once had and the Chrome Built Claws she once had attached, it's then Kia allows Ati to remember Gii and the love she had for him.

I am wondering, so far as i know the only continuation to this is the fact that M was originally interested in Ati because she had a Golden Eye but was too sociable but so far nothing in Shikkoku no Sharnoth -What a Beautiful Tomorrow- hints at what happened to Ati after she met, i am wondering if Ati's encounter with Prorishin and Kia is ever expanded on in any other works